# Harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not one-to-one, for $n\geq 2.$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Le $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a harmonic function. Prove that if $n\geq2$ then every $y\in Im\{u\}$ is attained infinite times, but it's not true for $n=1$.

I no have idea to start, someone has a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about harmonic function?

Comment: Hi @John, I know the properties of averages, analyticity, maximum principle...

Comment: By average do you mean the mean value property?

Comment: Yes, if $B(x,r)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so the average of $u$ over $B(x,r)$ (or $\partial B(x,r)$) is equals $u(x),$ since $u$ be a harmonic function.

Comment: This is gonna be useful. For example if $u(y) = c$, then for each $r$ there is $x$ so that $u(x) = c$ and $|x-y| = r$ (using the average property on $\partial B(y, r)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understood why this is useful.

Comment: Then $c$ is attains at least two times, but there are infinitely many choices of $r>0$....

Comment: If $u(y)=c$, then for each $r>0$ there is $x$, such that $\|x-y\|=r$, but why we have $u(x)=c$?

Comment: Because $c = u(y)$ is the average of $u(x)$ on $\partial B(y, r)$, so it is impossible that all values on this $\partial B(y, r)$ are $>c$ or $<c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if $u(y) = c$, then for each $r$ there is $x$ so that $u(x) = c$ and $|x-y| = r$. This is because $c = u(y)$ is the average of $u(x)$ on $\partial B(y, r)$, so it is impossible that all values on this $\partial B(y, r)$ are $>c$ or $<c$.

Since there are infinitely many choices of $r>0$, the value $c$ is attained infinitely many times.

(Taken from [John](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303547/harmonic-function-in-mathbbrn-is-not-one-to-one-for-n-geq-2#comment2647124_1303547)'s comments)